ember problem - ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\c:\ @warp-drive
I am trying to do an 'ember build' in a a 'ember new project' but i am getting all the time this strange message.
"
c:\Users\User\Desktop\ember-course\my-todo-app2>ember build
Environment: development
cleaning up...
Cleanup error.

cleaning upCannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cleanup')

Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp/error.dump.9dbb10a3d19dd2047e08aed890b5e922.log
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\c:\Users\User\Desktop\ember-course\my-todo-app2\node_modules@warp-drive\build-config\package.json'
Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp/error.dump.c69b18b56638bb0ac64f0267bc4bf249.log"
This is my version.
"c:\Users\User\Desktop\ember-course\my-todo-app2>ember -v
ember-cli: 5.9.0
node: 20.14.0
os: win32 x64"
I don't understand why it is searching the package.json in a path starting with c:\c:\ if the path had only one c:\ it was correct.

looks like your issue is with something accessing warp-drive, rather than exactly something ember specific -- it could be helpful to hop in the ember discord, and ask the ember-data / warp-drive team about windows support https://discord.gg/emberjs
